# The artifacts from feed (repository) is not getting downloaded in Agent of Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, mule, mule4

we are getting below error on Linux agent but when built on local machine it works fine.
ERROR:
The project 03b2fd5d-0ae4-4388-b2a3-d760d568ff1c:concur-system-service:2.0.0 (/home/vsts/work/1/s/pom.xml) has 1 error
2021-05-27T03:46:30.0918081Z [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for 03b2fd5d-0ae4-4388-b2a3-d760d568ff1c:concur-system-service:2.0.0: Could not find artifact com.crowley:enterprise-mule-parent-pom:pom:1.10.1-SNAPSHOT in enterprise (https://crowleymaritime.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Enterprise/_packaging/enterprise/maven/v1) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 15 -> [Help 2]
2021-05-27T03:46:30.0926300Z org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.crowley:enterprise-mule-parent-pom:pom:1.10.1-SNAPSHOT in enterprise (https://crowleymaritime.pkgs.visualstudio.com/Enterprise/_packaging/enterprise/maven/v1)
2021-05-27T03:46:30.0956011Z     at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:196)

Comment: This seems to be an issue with some Azure service. Please provide details. If there anything Mule specific about this issue? Or is it only related to Maven and Azure?

Answer (score 0):

If you use hosted Linux agent to run the pipeline, you can try changing the dependency entry in your pom.xml file to use all lower case letters.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
 <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
 <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Maven is case sensitive when run on a Linux platform. If you are running a Maven build on a Windows machine the upper case classifier would work. Here is the [reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-find-artifact-in-vsts/278473).